# Detecting if a key is HELD down - python

Tags: python, callback, keyboard, keyboard-events, pynput

### My use case

I need to know when a (specific) key is pressed and held down. The use case after detection is fairly easy. When the key is released, send a signal to stop the callback (which I know already).

### Desired behavior

Here is a rough scheme of how the algo looks like:

```
def the_callback():
    if key_held == the_hotkey:
        someObj.start()  # this class Obj works totally well so no issues here on
    elif key_released == the_hotkey:
        someObj.stop()
    else:
        # we don't care. continue looking for Keyboard events

# here any kinda listener or just a loop which passes events to the callback
```

I should mention that any kinda listener which blocks the execution is okay as it will run in its own thread (already running `pynput.keyboard.Listener` in a thread so not a problem)

### What I've tried

I used `pynput` and its `pynput.keyboard.Listener` to detect key-presses and invoke callbacks accordingly but I couldn't make that work to detect when a key is HELD down.

the current solution looks roughly like:

```
# not real code. just rough scheme
def on_pressed(key):
    if key == my_hotkey:
        if running_already:  # this part works well already
            obj.stop()
        else:
            obj.start()
    else:
        # we don't care

with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()  # blocking call until SystemExit, `return False` from callback or `listener.stop()`
```

**I have a very strong feeling** that I can make this work by adding `on_release=another_callback_that_handles_releases` (available within `pynput.keyboard.listener`).

Perhaps by storing the last known pressed keystroke, and checking if the key released was the same as the hotkey which was pressed earlier but I'm not sure how would I go about it and can that even work?

Then I decided to give `keyboard` (different lib) a go.
I wrote the below code for the same which can detect keys being held down. This below code achieves almost nearly what I want:

```
import keyboard as kb, time

while 1:
    while kb.is_pressed('q'):
        print('Key is held')
        time.sleep(0.5)  # sleep added just to stop it from spamming the stdout
        
    else:
        print('No it\'s Not')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

The issue with this solution is, it's not very well suited for OSX and Ubuntu. And it has some issues working with special keys. Moreover, I have the hotkey stored as `pynput.keyboard.Key.f7` (for eg) or `pynput.keyboard.KeyCode(char='s')  # for character keys` and these enums have different values than what `keyboard` uses to scan key IDs (using `keyboard.hook()`).

## The final question

How should I go about detecting a key being HELD down. I'd prefer to achieve this using `pynput` as the rest of the code base uses it but `'keyboard` is fine too.
Again I have a feeling that using `on_press=a_callback` and `on_release=another_callback` this might be achieved but I'm not entirely sure about it. Lastly, the solution is preferred to be cross platform (I'm fine with using three different functions depending on value of `platform.system()`).

How would you go about achieving it?

### EDIT-1

[HERE](https://gist.github.com/pssolanki111/f7ebea9eb7939577f31e2f392809ceb1) is what I wrote as an attempt (and MCVE) after suggestion by Isak. This works almost perfectly with *just 1* flaw. And that is that it doesn't listen to keypresses right from the program start.

It takes some time for some unknown reason before it starts to actually detect any keypress. Good thing is that once it detects the keypress for the first time, it works flawlessly.

What am I missing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check for `the key_pressed` event on the specific key until the event becomes `key_released`. So when you detect a click on the key you execute your code and when it detects the release of that key the code stops

Comment: [HERE](https://gist.github.com/pssolanki111/f7ebea9eb7939577f31e2f392809ceb1) is what I wrote as an attempt (and MCVE). This works almost perfectly with *just 1* flaw. And that is that it doesn't listen to keypresses right from the program start. It takes some time for some unknown reason before it starts to actually detects any keypress. Good thing is that once it detects the keypress for the first time, it works flawlessly. What am I missing there?

Comment: @PSSolanki the lag is probably because of the time it takes to import the keyboard module.

Comment: Appreciate the response, Sid! But I don't `import keyboard` in the script actually. And about the `pynput.keyboard.Listener` instance, I have a much bigger script which imports a lot more stuff including the ones in this mcve, and that works instantly. @Sid

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why [My Approach](https://gist.github.com/pssolanki111/f7ebea9eb7939577f31e2f392809ceb1) was taking a lot of time to initialize before starting the `Listener`. It was because of the while loop which didn't have any `time.sleep()` calls and it was probably messing with the system (although I wouldn't expect that to happen as it runs in its own thread but probably the `while` loop doesn't release the `GIL` as it's just in the loop doing literally nothing without any sort of delay).

I just added `time.sleep(0.2)` inside the while loop (the outer one). Any delay would do as that would release the `GIL` for some time and the `Listener` thread would be processed and made active.

Edit: Accepting the answer by Isak as accepted as that is the correct approach.